# How can I align two grouped tabulars so they are all aligned at the top with subcaptions?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions

I would like my tables to be aligned like this.
[image]

While having the grouping and caption of this

[image]

I only know of subfloat and it has been a bit annoying.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float,subfloat}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}



\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h]
    \centering

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \subfloat[Caption 1]{
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l|r}
        Koep & Abundance \\\hline
        Dfb &   167 \\
        Cfa &   150 \\
        BSk &   121 \\
        Dfc &   112 \\
        Csb &   106 \\
        Dsb &    56 \\
        Csa &    54 \\
        Dfa &    23 \\
        ET  &    17 \\
        Dsc &    15 \\
        Bwk &    15 \\
        Cfb &    14 \\
        Bwh &     5 \\
        Bsh &     4 \\
        Cfc &     4 \\
        Am  &     1 \\
        Aw  &     1 
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l|r}
        Koep &  Abundance \\\hline
        Dfb &    34 \\
        Cfa &    31 \\
        BSk &    30 \\
        Csa &    29 \\
        Dfc &    29 \\
        Csb &    23 \\
        Dsb &    17 \\
        Dfa &    11 \\
        Cfb &     2 \\
        ET  &     2 \\
        Bsh &     2 \\
        Dwa &     2 \\
        Bwh &     1 \\
        Dsc &     1 
        \end{tabular}}
    \quad
    \subfloat[caption 2]{
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l|r}
        Land Cover & Abundance\\\hline
        Grasslands           &    355 \\
        Savannah's             &    136 \\
        Woody Savannah's         &    120 \\
        Croplands            &    104 \\
        Deciduous Brdlf Frsts   &     44 \\
        Open Shrublands       &     37 \\
        Evergreen Ndllf Frsts  &     32 \\
        Mixed Frsts          &     21 \\
        Barren               &      7 \\
        Cropland/Veg Mosaic  &      3 \\
        Urban and Built-up     &      2 \\
        Evergreen Brdlf Frsts &      2 \\
        Closed Shrublands      &      2 
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l|r}
        Land Cover  &  Abundance \\\hline
        Grasslands           &     94 \\
        Savannah's             &     32 \\
        Croplands            &     31 \\
        Woody Savannah's          &     27 \\
        Deciduous Brdlf Frsts   &      8 \\
        Evergreen Brdlf Frsts  &      8 \\
        Open Shrublands       &      6 \\
        Mixed Frsts          &      4 \\
        Cropland/Veg Mosaic  &      2 \\
        Evergreen Brdlf Frsts &      1 \\
        Urban and Built-up     &      1 
        \end{tabular}}}
\centering
\caption{Caption }\label{tab:sec}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: While it's ok to upvote answers immediately if you find them useful, the site guidelines strongly recommend holding off on "accepting" any given answer for several hours, and maybe even a day or two. That way, you don't discourage would-be answer providers from posting additional, and possibly much better, answers.

Comment: My bad. Got excited that this issue I was trying to solve the last hour was alleviated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `subcaption`, you can first write the tables in two `subtable` environments aligned on top with the `t` option, and then add their captions with `\subcaptionbox`es of the same widths. Also, I'd advocate against using `\resizebox` as it messes up the font, and instead reduce the font size with `\scriptsize` or `\small` (if it fits) to make the font smaller.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \scriptsize
    \begin{subtable}[t]{.33\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l|r}
        Koep & Abundance \\\hline
        Dfb &   167 \\
        Cfa &   150 \\
        BSk &   121 \\
        Dfc &   112 \\
        Csb &   106 \\
        Dsb &    56 \\
        Csa &    54 \\
        Dfa &    23 \\
        ET  &    17 \\
        Dsc &    15 \\
        Bwk &    15 \\
        Cfb &    14 \\
        Bwh &     5 \\
        Bsh &     4 \\
        Cfc &     4 \\
        Am  &     1 \\
        Aw  &     1 
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l|r}
        Koep &  Abundance \\\hline
        Dfb &    34 \\
        Cfa &    31 \\
        BSk &    30 \\
        Csa &    29 \\
        Dfc &    29 \\
        Csb &    23 \\
        Dsb &    17 \\
        Dfa &    11 \\
        Cfb &     2 \\
        ET  &     2 \\
        Bsh &     2 \\
        Dwa &     2 \\
        Bwh &     1 \\
        Dsc &     1 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}\hfill
    \begin{subtable}[t]{.66\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l|r}
        Land Cover & Abundance\\\hline
        Grasslands           &    355 \\
        Savannah's             &    136 \\
        Woody Savannah's         &    120 \\
        Croplands            &    104 \\
        Deciduous Brdlf Frsts   &     44 \\
        Open Shrublands       &     37 \\
        Evergreen Ndllf Frsts  &     32 \\
        Mixed Frsts          &     21 \\
        Barren               &      7 \\
        Cropland/Veg Mosaic  &      3 \\
        Urban and Built-up     &      2 \\
        Evergreen Brdlf Frsts &      2 \\
        Closed Shrublands      &      2 
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tabular}[t]{l|r}
        Land Cover  &  Abundance \\\hline
        Grasslands           &     94 \\
        Savannah's             &     32 \\
        Croplands            &     31 \\
        Woody Savannah's          &     27 \\
        Deciduous Brdlf Frsts   &      8 \\
        Evergreen Brdlf Frsts  &      8 \\
        Open Shrublands       &      6 \\
        Mixed Frsts          &      4 \\
        Cropland/Veg Mosaic  &      2 \\
        Evergreen Brdlf Frsts &      1 \\
        Urban and Built-up     &      1 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}
    \subcaptionbox{Caption 1}[.33\textwidth]{}\hfill
    \subcaptionbox{caption 2}[.66\textwidth]{}
\caption{Caption }\label{tab:sec}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I appreciate you and your input. Thanks!

Comment: You may want to point out somewhere that your answer relies strongly on the `\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}` directive. With even slightly wider margins, the `tabular` environments will not fit next to each other unless one switches from `\scriptsize` to `\tiny`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `\resizebox` unless you really don't care about making the font size that's used in the table so small as to make the table's contents virtually unreadable.

I suggest you (a) change "Abundance" to "Abund." in all 4 `tabular` environments (to make the right-hand columns narrower) and (b) allow automatic line breaking in the left-hand columns, to make them narrower as well. It would also be nice to align the numbers in the right-hand columns on their (implicit) decimal markers. And, consider placing the captions at the top rather than at the bottom of the tables.

An application of these suggestions is given in the following code and associated screenshot. Note that the answer doesn't use `\resizebox` and gets by with a `\small` directive, for a 10% linear reduction in font size, instead of `\scriptsize`, which reduces the font size linearly by 30%.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{subcaption}  % for 'subtable' env.
\usepackage{array}       % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\usepackage{ragged2e}    % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\usepackage{siunitx}     % for 'S' column type
\newlength\mylen
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{% automatic linebreaking, hanging indentation
    >{\RaggedRight\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}p{#1}}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\small % for a 10% linear font size reduction
\settowidth\mylen{Open Shrublll} % found by trial and error

\caption{Caption}\label{tab:sec}

\begin{subtable}[t]{0.37\textwidth}
\caption{Caption 1}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l | S[table-format=3.0] @{}}
        Koep & {Abund.} \\
        \hline
        Dfb &   167 \\
        Cfa &   150 \\
        BSk &   121 \\
        Dfc &   112 \\
        Csb &   106 \\
        Dsb &    56 \\
        Csa &    54 \\
        Dfa &    23 \\
        ET  &    17 \\
        Dsc &    15 \\
        Bwk &    15 \\
        Cfb &    14 \\
        Bwh &     5 \\
        Bsh &     4 \\
        Cfc &     4 \\
        Am  &     1 \\
        Aw  &     1 
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l | S[table-format=2.0] @{}}
        Koep &  {Abund.} \\
        \hline
        Dfb &    34 \\
        Cfa &    31 \\
        BSk &    30 \\
        Csa &    29 \\
        Dfc &    29 \\
        Csb &    23 \\
        Dsb &    17 \\
        Dfa &    11 \\
        Cfb &     2 \\
        ET  &     2 \\
        Bsh &     2 \\
        Dwa &     2 \\
        Bwh &     1 \\
        Dsc &     1 
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}\hfill
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.58\textwidth}
\caption{Caption 2}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} P{\mylen} | S[table-format=3.0] @{}}
        Land Cover & {Abund.}\\
        \hline
        Grasslands           &    355 \\
        Savannahs            &    136 \\
        Woody Savannahs      &    120 \\
        Croplands            &    104 \\
        Deciduous Brdlf Frsts&     44 \\
        Open Shrublands      &     37 \\
        Evergreen Ndllf Frsts&     32 \\
        Mixed Frsts          &     21 \\
        Barren               &      7 \\
        Cropland\slash Veg Mosaic & 3 \\
        Urban and Built-up   &      2 \\
        Evergreen Brdlf Frsts&      2 \\
        Closed Shrublands    &      2 
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} P{\mylen} | S[table-format=2.0] @{}}
        Land Cover  &  {Abund.} \\
        \hline
        Grasslands           &     94 \\
        Savannahs            &     32 \\
        Croplands            &     31 \\
        Woody Savannahs      &     27 \\
        Deciduous Brdlf Frsts&      8 \\
        Evergreen Brdlf Frsts&      8 \\
        Open Shrublands      &      6 \\
        Mixed Frsts          &      4 \\
        Cropland\slash Veg Mosaic & 2 \\
        Evergreen Brdlf Frsts&      1 \\
        Urban and Built-up   &      1 
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: It may be instructive to compare the solution given above with the one given in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/673400/5001), which doesn't attempt to reduce the column widths. Same text width, and I've helped the alternative solution out by reducing the value of `\tabcolsep` and by eliminating the whitespace padding on the left- and right-hand edges of the `tabular` environments. My solution uses `\small`, while the other uses `\tiny` (for a 50% linear reduction in font size). I suppose it's fair to say that there's an enormous difference in legibility.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Now mostly off-topic, but you may liked ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx, counter}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \footnotesize
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.33\linewidth}
\begin{talltblr}[
    label=none,     % <---
    entry=none,     % <---
                ]{baseline= t,
                  colspec = {@{} l | Q[c, si={table-format=3.0{1}}] @{}},
                  row{1} = {guard}}
    Koep & Ab.\TblrNote{1} \\
    \hline
    Dfb &   167 \\
    Cfa &   150 \\
    BSk &   121 \\
    Dfc &   112 \\
    Csb &   106 \\
    Dsb &    56 \\
    Csa &    54 \\
    Dfa &    23 \\
    ET  &    17 \\
    Dsc &    15 \\
    Bwk &    15 \\
    Cfb &    14 \\
    Bwh &     5 \\
    Bsh &     4 \\
    Cfc &     4 \\
    Am  &     1 
\end{talltblr}\quad 
\begin{talltblr}[
    label=none,     % <---
    entry=none,     % <---
note{1} = {Abundance}
                ]{baseline= t,
                  colspec = {@{} l | Q[c, si={table-format=2.0{1}}] @{}},
                   row{1} = {guard}}
    Koep & Ab.\TblrNote{1} \\
    \hline
    Aw  &     1 \\
    Dfb &    34 \\
    Cfa &    31 \\
    BSk &    30 \\
    Csa &    29 \\
    Dfc &    29 \\
    Csb &    23 \\
    Dsb &    17 \\
    Dfa &    11 \\
    Cfb &     2 \\
    ET  &     2 \\
    Bsh &     2 \\
    Dwa &     2 \\
    Bwh &     1 \\
    Dsc &     1 \\
    \hline  
\end{talltblr}
\caption{Sub caption 1}
    \end{subtable}
\hfill
\begin{subtable}[t]{0.66\linewidth}
\begin{talltblr}[
    label=none,     % <---
    entry=none,     % <---
                ]{baseline=t,
                  colspec = {@{} l | Q[c, si={table-format=3.0{1}}] @{}},
                   rowsep = 1pt,
                   row{1} = {guard}}
Land Cover & Ab.\TblrNote{1} \\
    \hline
    Grasslands              &    355 \\
    Savannah's              &    136 \\
    Woody Savannah's        &    120 \\
    Croplands               &    104 \\
    Deciduous Brdlf Frsts   &     44 \\
    Open Shrublands         &     37 \\
    Evergreen Ndllf Frsts   &     32 \\
    Mixed Frsts             &     21 \\
    Barren                  &      7 \\
    Cropland/Veg Mosaic     &      3 \\
    Urban and Built-up      &      2 \\
    Evergreen Brdlf Frsts   &      2 
\end{talltblr}\quad 
\begin{talltblr}[
    label=none,     % <---
    entry=none,     % <---
note{1} = {Abundance}
                ]{baseline=t,
                  colspec = {@{} l | Q[c, si={table-format=2.0{1}}] @{}},
                   rowsep = 1pt,
                   row{1} = {guard}}
Land Cover & Ab.\TblrNote{1}        \\
    \hline
    Closed Shrublands       &      2 \\
    Grasslands              &     94 \\
    Savannah's              &     32 \\
    Croplands               &     31 \\
    Woody Savannah's        &     27 \\
    Deciduous Brdlf Frsts   &      8 \\
    Evergreen Brdlf Frsts   &      8 \\
    Open Shrublands         &      6 \\
    Mixed Frsts             &      4 \\
    Cropland/Veg Mosaic     &      2 \\
    Evergreen Brdlf Frsts   &      1 \\
    Urban and Built-up      &      1 \\
    \hline 
\end{talltblr}
\caption{Sub caption 1}
    \end{subtable}

\caption{Common caption}
\label{tab:sec}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]